# Texture too dull / dark in render

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I enjoy making 'paper' animations in Blender, but I can never set the colors properly.
Picture on the left shows how the textures are supposed to look like, the one on the right shows how they actually look like in render (after a little correction in Color Management). A little off, and the grey "white" bothers me the most. Blend Mode is set to Alpha Hashed, and Shadow Mode is set to None.

[image]

I tried adjusting the colors with nodes (Emission, Saturation/Value) and Color Management, but they only made the colors more washed out and pale. Are there any other nodes or options I could use to make the textures exactly as they appear in their png versions?

Comment: Damn, beat me to it haha

Comment: @Geri, I believe you agree, it is a very common question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your *View Transform* to *Standard* in your *Properties* tab under *Render Properties* -> *Color Management*

[image]

Comment: I can't believe the solution was this simple! Thank you so much, you've saved me a lot of headache.